# Opencv2 cannot compile with Xcode7.1

Tags: ios, ios9, opencv3.0, xcode7.1

[image]

Opencv2 cannot compile with Xcode7.1

Comment: Please share relevant code and error as text, not as image!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure This Way is correct but you can try this step :

-> first right click on Opencv2 framework and choose "show in finder"

-> copy Opencv2 framework and paste Any Other Location

-> Remove Refrence Opencv2 framework in your Project

-> Clean And Add Opencv2 framework we Copied Before

-> clean and build

May Be it's work